# Detect Multiple/Shared Logins from Stats Log

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

We run a website where sharing login details is not allowed, however system was never built to prevent these users. Now management want a report of those who are sharing. I'm pretty sure we can find them by analyzing our stats database.

My idea for detecting sharing logins is to query the stats tables (MSSQL 2008) at the end of each month and produce a list of suspects.  To catch them I need a query that will show a "switching" session/ipaddress.

For example, the following is allowed:

```
DateTime, UserId, SessionId, IpAddress
12Feb13 16:30, 10, ABC, x.x.x.x
12Feb13 16:32, 10, ABC, x.x.x.x
12Feb13 16:34, 10, DEF, y.y.y.y
12Feb13 16:36, 10, DEF, y.y.y.y
```

The following is **not** allowed:

```
DateTime, UserId, SessionId, IpAddress
12Feb13 16:30, 10, ABC, x.x.x.x
12Feb13 16:32, 10, DEF, y.y.y.y
12Feb13 16:34, 10, ABC, x.x.x.x
12Feb13 16:36, 10, DEF, y.y.y.y
```

The question is how to do this effectively when querying thousands and thousands of entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:** I erased my prior CTE answer because the only way I could make it work was by using `LAG` which isn't available on SQL 2008.  None the less, I came up with something that runs faster.*

The following splits the data into two CTEs, the first returns the range of time a sessionID occurs for a user, and the second is the range for ip addresses.  If a session begins within the range of an ip address, but finishes outside of that range then the session must have been part of a different ip address.  Likewise if a session starts before an ip, but finishes within an ip then it is also bad.

This solution assumes that a sessionID can only be used once per user -- that once their session ends for an ip, the id number can't be used at a later time.

```
SELECT s.UserId, s.SessionId, s.IpAddress, i.IpAddress, s.MinDate [sMin], s.MaxDate [sMax],
    i.MinDate [iMin], i.MaxDate [iMax]
FROM (

    SELECT UserID, SessionID, IPAddress, MIN(DT) MinDate, MAX(DT) MaxDate
    FROM #USERLOG  
    GROUP BY UserID, SessionID, IPAddress

) AS s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, IPAddress, MIN(DT) MinDate, MAX(DT) MaxDate
    FROM #USERLOG ipLog 
    GROUP BY UserID, IPAddress
) AS i ON 
    s.UserID = i.UserID 
    AND s.IpAddress != i.IpAddress
    AND (
        (s.MinDate < i.MaxDate AND s.MaxDate > i.MaxDate) OR 
        (s.MinDate < i.MinDate AND s.MaxDate > i.MinDate))
```

For best performance you'll need indexes for `UserID, Session, IPAddress` and `UserID, SessionID`.

Comment: You sir, are a master!